# Why does different types of array subscript used to iterate affect auto vectorization

Tags: c++, arrays, uint64, uint32, auto-vectorization

As following code shows, why `uint32_t` prevents the compiler (GCC 12.1 + O3) from optimizing by auto vectorization. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a3GfaKEq6).

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

// no auto vectorization
void test32(uint32_t *array, uint32_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to) {
    for (uint32_t i = from; i < to; i++) {
        array[nread++] = i;
    }
}

// auto vectorization
void test64(uint32_t *array, uint64_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to) {
    for (uint32_t i = from; i < to; i++) {
        array[nread++] = i;
    }
}

// no auto vectorization
void test_another_32(uint32_t *array, uint32_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to) {
    uint32_t index = nread;
    for (uint32_t i = from; i < to; i++) {
        array[index++] = i;
    }
    nread = index;
}

// auto vectorization
void test_another_64(uint32_t *array, uint32_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to) {
    uint64_t index = nread;
    for (uint32_t i = from; i < to; i++) {
        array[index++] = i;
    }
    nread = index;
}
```

After I ran the command `g++ -O3 -fopt-info-vec-missed -c test.cc -o /dev/null`, I got the following result. How to interpret it?

```bash
bash> g++ -O3 -fopt-info-vec-missed -c test.cc -o /dev/null
test.cc:5:31: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cc:6:24: missed: not vectorized: not suitable for scatter store *_5 = i_18;
test.cc:21:31: missed: couldn't vectorize loop
test.cc:22:24: missed: not vectorized: not suitable for scatter store *_4 = i_22;
```

Comment: Is this just a thought question or are you trying to solve an actual problem? If this is supposed to solve an actual problem, i feel like the best solution would be to not write C style code in C++. If this were written using C++ the compiler will vectorize when it makes sense to vectorize, and unroll when it makes sense to unroll.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function

```
void test32(uint32_t *array, uint32_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to)
```

and how it should behave if you call it like this:

```
uint32_t arr[16];
test32(arr, arr[3], &arr[0], &arr[15]);
```

This is called aliasing. The `nread` parameter might alias elements from `array` because they have the same type. But when you have

```
void test64(uint32_t *array, uint64_t &nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to)
```

then no aliasing can occur because an `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` can never have the same address.

Note: passing a reference to a function internally passes the address so it's equivalent to a pointer for the argument of aliasing.

There are some types with special rules called aliasing types. The C++ standard says that you can cast an `uint32_t*` to `char*` and then access the raw memory underlying the `uint32_t`. That means an `uint32_t*` and `char*` can legally point at the same address. `char*` is an aliasing type because it aliases with any other type of (data) pointer. So is `unsigned char*` or any other variation of `char` including `std::byte`.

But you can tell the compiler that 2 pointers are not allowed to alias even if the type would permit it by using [restrict](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict).

```
void test32(uint32_t *array, uint32_t & restrict nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to)
```

PS: `test_another_32` looks like a missed compiler optiomization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added `__restrict__` to `nread` like this ```void test32(uint32_t *array, uint32_t & __restrict__ nread, uint32_t from, uint32_t to)```, but the compiler still doesn't optimize it by auto vectorization. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1xMKov763).

Comment: clang does: https://godbolt.org/z/Kbs1cdW3Y Might be worth reporting to gcc. Looks like missed optimizations.

Comment: I checked clang, it works as you said after adding `__restrict__` to `test32` and clang also optimizes `test_another_32`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow *"This is called aliasing."* No, this is invalid C++. The function call that you have in your given example won't compile. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/xZi0qotSU)

Comment: @AnoopRana Fixed the typo. It's still called aliasing though.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yeah, i was just emphasizing that this is called invalid C++. Now, its fine.

Comment: Restrict is a c feature, not c++. Is _not_ part of the c++ standard.

Comment: @Taekahn which I hope they will fix. __restrict__ works in gcc/clang though as extension.

Comment: Hi @GoswinvonBrederlow , I asked **gcc-help** for help. Someone explained that there is another issue with `test32`. It is that the value of `index` may be wrapped around from 0xffffffff to 0, making the access non-consecutive. You can refer to the [conversation](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-help/2022-June/141742.html).

Comment: That makes sense. One more reason to always use std::size_t for indexes.